# Datatable select value where field type is unknown or at run time

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

i have a simple linq query

```
linqdt.AsEnumerable()
      .Where(w => (w.Field<string>(options.SelectedColumn)).Contains(options.Value))
      .CopyToDataTable();
```

this will return me result if SelectedColumn type is of string (a.Field).
Now my problem is option.SelectedColumn could be of multiple types. It could be of byte, date, guid etc etc and i don't know these types until run time.

I was wondering if there is any way i can pass a variable like w.Field and that variable contains the datatype based on SelectedColumn? If NO, what could be other possibilities?

Any Help Will Be Highly Appreciated

Comment: what is the type of linqdt

Comment: @ibiza, `DataTable` *(I guess from the name `dt` and `AsEnumerable` and `Field<T>` extension method)*

Comment: yeah @Habib is right, its a datatable

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, your `Where` isn't actually doing any filtering. Could you tell us more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: @CoderDennis, Thanks to Ehsan , he made it readable.

Comment: Oh, I see. I wasn't seeing the sets of parenthesis correctly.

Comment: `.Contains()` does not make sense for non-string values  -would you use `Equals` in that case?

Comment: @DStanley,interesting point, I haven't thought about that!!

Answer (score 1):

Since `Contains` only applies to string values, I would use an `if` statement to check string values, and use the non-generic column accessor and `Equals` for other columns:

```
DataTable result;
if(linqdt.Columns[options.SelectedColumn].DataType == typeof(string))

    result = linqdt.AsEnumerable()
                   .Where(w => (w.Field<string>(options.SelectedColumn))
                                 .Contains(options.Value))
                   .CopyToDataTable();
else
    result = linqdt.AsEnumerable()
                   .Where(w => (w[options.SelectedColumn]).Equals(options.Value))
                   .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: its not giving me any result means result datatable is empty. Though datatable selected column does contain the value